# Share Data (cookie) on different domain in angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Share data(cookie or any other way)on two different angular project, which are running on two different domain in angular 2

I using angular2-cookie pkg with "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6" version,
for set cookie, with
`put(key: string, value: string, options?: CookieOptionsArgs): void;` &
`get(key: string): string;` provided functions
in two different projects.
OR is their any another way for sharing data

```
 import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/core';

  //In project one i.e running on http://www.xyz.in/ domain
  this.CookieService.put('username','my name is abc',
  {domain:'http://www.abc.in/'})

  //In project two i.e running on http://www.abc.in/ domain
  this.CookieService.get('username')
  console.log(this.CookieService.get('username'))
```

In above case
expected result is it should display
my name is abc
But actual output is
undefined 
in project 2 i.e http://www.abc.in/

Comment: welcome to SO, you can't access the cookie between the different domain , alteast not directly. but for subdomain you can access like say cookie from `foo.example.com` can be accessed in `bar.example.com`

Answer (score 1):

You can not set the Cookie for other domain, it would be very dangerous.

Comment: Ok, but is their any another way for sharing the data on different project.

Comment: If there is no backend ==> they should be in the same domain, or one of them is a sub-domain of other one.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I achieved this task by dynamic routing.

Comment: @AshwiniDemouser- I am looking for same. Can you please help me for the same?